# How do I use an array of values as an array/hash path?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I.e., how do I come from this:

```
path = [ 1, 3, 4, 5 ... ]
```

to this:

```
my_array[1][3][4][5]...
```

The length of the `path` array is unknown.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the new (Ruby 2.3) `dig` method like so:

```
my_array.dig(1, 3, 4, 5)
```

Or pass it your splatted array:

```
path = [1, 3, 4, 5]
my_array.dig(*path)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `inject` combined with `[]`:

```
irb(main):001:0> arr = [[[[0, 1]]]]
=> [[[[0, 1]]]]
irb(main):002:0> [0, 0, 0, 1].inject(arr, :[])
=> 1
```

This recursively 'unpacks' arr with `[]` until `inject` runs out of path elements.

This doesn't require a specific version (`inject` has been part of Enumerable since Ruby 1.8 at least) but might require a comment explaining what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the way to go, but just for fun:

```
def build_path(array, path)
  eval "#{array}#{path.map { |el| "[#{el}]" }.join}"
end
build_path([1,2], [1])
#=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it autovivication you mean ? See http://t-a-w.blogspot.be/2006/07/autovivification-in-ruby.html

You can do that like this

```
def hash_tree
  Hash.new do |hash, key|
    hash[key] = hash_tree
  end
end

myhash = hash_tree 
myhash[1][2][3][4] = 5
myhash # {1=>{2=>{3=>{4=>5}}}}
myhash[1][2][3][4] # 5
```

or if you prefer the example from the blog

```
def autovivifying_hash
  Hash.new {|ht,k| ht[k] = autovivifying_hash}
end
```